# QML Button press and release color

Tags: qt, button, styles, qml

Following is the sample Button QML code that I found in google:

```
    Button {
    id: myButton
    text: "btnTxt";
    function buttonClick()
    {
    console.log("Button "+ myButton.text +" is clicked!")
    }

       MouseArea {
           id: myMouseId
           anchors.fill: parent
           onClicked:
           {
               myButton.buttonClick();
           }
        }

       style: ButtonStyle {
           background:
                Rectangle {
                   color: myMouseId.pressed ? "#336699" : "#0099FF";
                    radius: 1;
                }
       }

    }
```

And I am using the following imports:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
```

But, Qt threw the error:
**Invalid property assignment: "pressed" is a read-only property**

Also, is there an complete example for this basic type? I couldn't find in the doc how to address the above condition.

Comment: Your code is working for me without any changes.

Comment: Thanks :) It's working for me too :) Found a silly mistake elsewhere -.-